# Are there alternatives to the .get function in C++?

Tags: c++, function, input

I am an extremely novice developer, in my third week of learning C++ in college. We've just been introduced to the .get function as a way to take in whitespace characters with cin, but to me, it seems as though this is an inefficient way to go about including whitespace characters when many variables need to have values assigned to them from many inputs. Is there an alternative that allows for one to systematically choose which whitespace characters to include or exclude in a long line of inputs that isn't manual, besides creating some function for the purpose yourself?

Comment: See the example in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt

Comment: See also `std::getline`.